# Why is this "in" statement not evaluating to True?

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

I have this code here

```
input1 = input("Toppings: ")
split = input1.split("|")
length = len(split)

for i in range(0, length-1):
  if "cheese" in str(split[i]):
    del split[i]

s = "|"
print(s.join(split))
```

and it's meant to take a string, split it by `"|"` into an array, then search the array for the string `"cheese"`, and if it finds it; take it out of the array, and then print out the parsed array.

When inputting this:

```
Toppings: ham|lettuce|cheddar cheese|sliced cucumber|tomato
ham|lettuce|sliced cucumber|tomato
```

The output is correct - it removes the element that has `"cheese"` in it from the array. However, when inputting this:

```
Toppings: egg|lettuce|cheese spread|mac'n'cheese
egg|lettuce|mac'n'cheese
```

It doesn't remove it from the array. When I looked up the `in` operator it said it *didn't* match whole word only so I thought it would work. What would be the correct code to put into the `if` statement so it would detect `"cheese"` in `"mac'n'cheese"`?

Comment: why are you working with indexes and not elements? Why can't you just say `for i in split`??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
for i in range(0, length-1):
```

The end of the range is already exclusive. You can do:

```
for i in range(0, length):
```

But this will throw an exception, as the pointer will pass the end of the array. The simple way to fix it is to do:

```
i = 0
while i<len(split):
  if "cheese" in str(split[i]):
    del split[i]
  else:
    i += 1
```

Comment: When I try this I get an error: `IndexError: list index out of range` - which is why I did length-1 because that worked.

Comment: This isn't the problem he's running into, and this isn't the right solution, but this is a problem; it's coincidence that `length-1` works.

Comment: Thanks for editing it, it's working now! *Will accept answer when it lets me*

Comment: I prefer to go in reverse direction, it's much pretty: `for i in range(length, 0, -1): if "cheese" in str(split[i]): del split[i-1]`

Comment: The problem is that the list is being modified as it's iterated. This solution is unreliable.

Comment: This will not work as the list shrinks and if "cheese" in one of the cell i will go out of bound towards the end.

Comment: This solution works. It has minimum allocations, although it is not pretty nor actually fast. I just don't get why this deserves a downvote in Python. I'm not a Python programmer, but I'm pretty sure this is not what downvotes should mean in StackOverflow.

Comment: @JuanLopes, I'm not the one who downvoted you, and your code does work, but it isn't very Pythonic. Which is understandable, since you said you're not a Python programmer. This code is much more imperative than it needs to be; you only need to get that far into the weeds in exceptional cases, which this is not.

Answer (score 4):

You're modifying the list while iterating over it. Specifically, because you're removing items, but not adjusting the index, you're skipping over things; in this case, `mac'n'cheese`.

You also have another problem you're happening to not run into with those inputs. Since each sample input is only having one element removed, `range(0, length-1)` happens to not give an `IndexError`; but if more than one element was being removed, it would.

Here's a much better way to do what you're trying to do:

```
toppings = input("Toppings: ").split('|')

toppings_without_cheese = (top for top in toppings if 'cheese' not in top)

print('|'.join(toppings_without_cheese))
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a separate array and ADD allowed values to that instead of removing the disallowed ones. See "allowedToppings" and how I switched the If statement below.

```
input1 = input("Toppings: ")
split = input1.split("|")
length = len(split)

allowedToppings = []
for i in range(0, length-1):
    if not "cheese" in str(split[i]):
        allowedToppings.append(str(split[i]))

s = "|"
print(s.join(split))
```